# In Neovim where is {lhs} of triggering a keymap stored? Can we access it?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

If we set a keymap that `{lhs}` is abc in normal mode. For example,

```
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
vim.keymap.set('n', 'abc', function() print("Keymap abc!"), opts)
```

If we type `abc` in normal mode, where is the `abc` stored? Can we access it?

Comment: Could you tell us more about your goal? I suppose it will help us to help you? By definition of the mapping it is triggered when `abc` is typed.

Comment: Hi. Pardon me for the unclear description. 
In this question, I mean: in normal mode, neovim must "memorize/store" `ab` we just typed to be ready for triggering the map when we type `c`. I guess that there may be somewhere neovim "memorizes/stores" `ab`. 
Maybe `ab` is "memorized/stored" in some kind of "register" like mark register (e.g., `ma` marked in register `a`), yank register (e.g., `"ay` yanked in register `a`), or recording register (e.g., `qa` recorded in register `a`)? 
My goal is to access that "register", and I hope it can be used in the function part of `vim.keymap.set()`.

Comment: Thanks it is clear. Is your goal is to use the same function for multiple mappings and to access the keybuffer to decide what to do in the function?

Comment: Yes! In the same `vim.keymap.set()` setting, I would like that the function take, e.g., (if we type `abc`) `c` in `abc` to do some process in the function, and (if we type `abd`) `d` to do the other process in the same function. Wait. So I have to set for `abc` and `abd` separately?

Comment: you can map `ab` and in your function call `getchar()` to get the next character and act upon this

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks! I will try this way.